# How can I perform unit test on my ES service?

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, testing, elasticsearch-5

I would like to perform unit tests on my service, that basically searches data in ES cluster using ES client. How to do this? Could anyone provide any example?

I found that I should use `ESTestCase` class but unfortunately [documentation says literally nothing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/unit-tests.html) and also I cannot find any examples in the Internet - if there are examples there are rather for intergration testing in which I'm not interested about.